# Big differences between AC and DC measurements

Tags: power, measurement, energy

I am conducting some electricity measurements with [Tinkerforge](https://www.tinkerforge.com/en/). To be more precise, I am measuring the energy consumption of a RPi 4, and for that I use two Tinkerforge bricklets.

The first one, [energy monitor](https://www.tinkerforge.com/de/shop/energy-monitor-bricklet.html) is measuring AC and the second one, [voltage/current](https://www.tinkerforge.com/de/shop/voltage-current-v2-bricklet.html) bricklet, is measuring DC.

I understand that because of how electricity is being measured, the values would be different, but I still find it confusing how come the measured power is 10 times different.

Here is a picture of the energy monitor bricklet where you can see that the *real power* is 32.90 W:

[image: Energy monitor bricklet]

And here is a screen shot of the voltage/current which measures the power at 2.314 W.

[image: voltage/current]

I would be very thankful if anyone could explain to me why I get such different values.

Comment: Show us your setup, where is your current clamp connected etc. Take a photo of your entire setup! I assume you have a setup like in the video with 2 extension cords: Is RPI the only load plugged in the extension cord?

Comment: To me, there are a few likely scenarios: (1) The AC measurement is wildly inaccurate because of the nature of the current being drawn, or (2) The AC-to-DC power supply feeding your Rpi is inefficient. I somehow doubt your mains device is dissipating 25+ watts so it's possible that the AC sensor brick just isn't that accurate for extremely light loads. Also the AC/DC power supply could be running in burst mode which the sensor brick may or may not be able to properly handle.

Answer (score 1):

The measurements are likely correct, within a small percentage of error.

32.9W is what the power supply is actually using from the mains.

However. 97.07VA (Volt*Amps is really the same units as Watts) is what the power supply is *reacting* with on the mains.

The ratio of real power (W) versus apparent power (VA) defines the power-factor of the device.  For this supply, the power factor is pretty atrocious (0.33), implying that it is probably a transformer-based linear supply.  It also seems to be much larger than it needs to be (say, rated for 5 V / 15 A output and only 0.5 A is actually used.)

If the RPi current will never go above 0.5 A, consider using a USB charger.  Those can readily be found with 5 V / 1 A output and should "waste" much less power.

Comment: Your parenthetical "Volt*Amps is really the same unit as Watts" is confusing, especially since the very next paragraph explains the difference. Also, if you reread the question, they're not even asking about the VA measurement.